# how do multi select in Asp.net bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-4, multi-select

Now i am getting result like this
[image]

[image]
[image]
enter image description here
[image]

Comment: attached images are my code behind for Multi select. but it is not working. please help me

Comment: `chosen.jquery.js` is not "bootstrap" and you've included it twice

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for you reply. instead of chosen.jquery.js which one i can use for bootstrap.

Comment: To make a `select` multi select, just add the `multiple` attribute: `<select id="mselect" multiple>`
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Comment: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Multiple-Select-MultiSelect-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery.aspx

Comment: Please post your code, not the screen shots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by adding  multiple="true" to your select. I also script mine a bit different, but it works great. You will note I am using the class and not the id of the select box.
See below example - you will note I am binding the select from my database, but you can do it hardcoded as well, as in your example.

```
<select class="chosen-select form-control" data-placeholder="Select One or More Options" multiple="true" id="SelectedMachines" runat="server"></select>

$(function () {
    $('.chosen-select').chosen();
    $('.chosen-select-deselect').chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
});
```